# Get top 5 records for each group and Concate them in a Row per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, common-table-expression

I have a table `Contacts` that basically looks like following:

```
Id | Name | ContactId |  Contact   | Amount
---------------------------------------------
1  |  A   |     1     | 12323432   |  555
---------------------------------------------
1  |  A   |     2     | 23432434   |  349
---------------------------------------------
2  |  B   |     3     | 98867665   |  297
--------------------------------------------
2  |  B   |     4     | 88867662   |  142
--------------------------------------------
2  |  B   |     5     |   null     |  698
--------------------------------------------
```

Here, `ContactId` is unique throughout the table. `Contact` can be `NULL` & I would like to exclude those.

Now, I want to select top 5 contacts for each Id based on their `Amount`. I am accomplished that by following query:

```
 WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, Contact, amount, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY id
        order by amount desc
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM contacts
    where contact is not null
)
select *from cte where RowNo <= 5
```

It's working fine upto this point. Now I want to concate these (<=5) record for each group & show them in a single row by concatenating them.

Expected Result :

```
 Id | Name | Contact
-------------------------------
  1  |  A   | 12323432;23432434   
-------------------------------
  2  |  B   | 98867665;88867662
```

I am using following query to achieve this but it still gives all records in separate rows and also including `Null` values too:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, Contact, amount,contactid, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY id
        order by amount desc
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM contacts
    where contact is not null
)
select *from id, name, 
STUFF ((
          SELECT distinct  '; ' + isnull(contact,'')   FROM cte 
          WHERE co.id= cte.id and co.contactid= cte.contactid
          and RowNo <= 5
 FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')as contact
 from contacts co inner join cte where cte.id = co.id and co.contactid= cte.contactid
```

Above query still gives me all top 5 contacts in diff rows & including null too.

Is it a good idea to use `CTE` and `STUFF` togather? Please suggest if there is any better approach than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem with my final query:

I don't need original `Contact` table in my final `Select`, since I already have everything I needed in `CTE`. Also, Inside `STUFF()`, I'm using `contactid` to join which is what actually I'm trying to concat here. Since I'm using that condition for join, I am getting records in diff rows. I've removed these 2 condition and it worked.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, Contact, amount,contactid, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY id
        order by amount desc
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM contacts
    where contact is not null
)
select *from id, name, 
STUFF ((
          SELECT distinct  '; ' + isnull(contact,'')   FROM cte 
          WHERE co.id= cte.id              
          and RowNo <= 5
 FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')as contact
 from  cte where rowno <= 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:
id, name, contact,

```
select id, name,
       concat(max(case when seqnum = 1 then contact + ';' end),
              max(case when seqnum = 2 then contact + ';' end),
              max(case when seqnum = 3 then contact + ';' end),
              max(case when seqnum = 4 then contact + ';' end),
              max(case when seqnum = 5 then contact + ';' end)
             ) as contacts              
from (select c.*
             row_number() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from contacts c
      where contact is not null
     ) c
group by id, name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SQL Server 2017 or higher, you can use `string_agg()`: as most other aggregate functions, it ignores `null` values by design.

```
select id, name, string_agg(contact, ',') within group (order by rn) all_contacts
from (
    select id, name, contact
        row_number() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as rn 
    from contacts
    where contact is not null
) t
where rn <= 5
group by id, name
```

Note that you don't strictly need a CTE here; you can return the columns you need from the subquery, and use them directly in the outer query.

In earlier versions, one approach using `stuff()` and `for xml path` is:

```
with cte as (
    select id, name, contact, 
        row_number() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as rn 
    from contacts
    where contact is not null
)
select id, name, 
    stuff(
        (
            select ', ' + c1.concat
            from cte c1
            where c1.id = c.id and c1.rn <= 5
            order by c1.rn
            for xml path (''), type
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
    ) all_contacts
from cte
group by id, name
```

Comment: Thank you but I think we're using  SQL Server 2012 or lower.

Comment: yes. I was trying different things & got the issue & posted same. Your answer is also seems correct but i don't think you need `group by` there.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @GMB. STRING_AGG() is what you need ...

```
WITH
contacts(Id,nm,ContactId,Contact,Amount) AS (
          SELECT 1,'A',1,12323432,555
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'A',2,23432434,349
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'B',3,98867665,297
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'B',4,88867662,142
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'B',5,NULL    ,698
)
,
with_filter_val AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY amount DESC) AS rn
  FROM contacts
)
SELECT
  id
, nm
, STRING_AGG(CAST(contact AS CHAR(8)),',') AS contact_list
FROM with_filter_val
WHERE rn <=5
GROUP BY
  id
, nm
-- out  id | nm |   contact_list    
-- out ----+----+-------------------
-- out   1 | A  | 12323432,23432434
-- out   2 | B  | 98867665,88867662
```

Comment: I'm aware of that but as I mentioned in comment, Life would be much easier if i could have just used function like `String_Split()` and `String_Agg()`. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Not if you need to add a ranking / top n evaluation in the process ...